# CSS property for a HTML tag when body has not class

Tags: css

I have a div with the class `.fa-times` for which I need `display:none` when the body does not have a specific class (e.g. `.mm-wrapper_opening`).

I tried:

```
body:not(.mm-wrapper_opening) .fa-times {
  display: none!important;
}
```

when

```
<body class="mm-wrapper ext-webkit ext-chrome ext-linux">
```

Is it possible to check an existing class in a wrapping tag? If yes, what's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 4):

check this out !

```
.fa-times{display:none;}
body.mm-wrapper .fa-times{display:block;}
```

Use this logic :
if body have this class then show

Comment: Thank you! But mm-wrapper is an always existing class. I can actually only evaluate .mm-wrapper_opening in the body.

Comment: Actually it's the same thing. If exist then show. If not exist element won't shown up